# How to change background/wallpaper to picture in IDLE python?

Tags: tkinter, python-idle

I'm trying to change IDLE's background/wallpaper to a picture (not a specific color). Is it even possible? Or should i use something like "JetBrains PyCharm" (if its possible there). Most important for me is customization.

I have googled a lot and i didn't find anything related to changing background to picture. All i have found is how to change colors of text and background.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I found how to do it in PyCharm |[here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-background-image.html)|.
Im still curious, if you know the answer to original question let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm very curious why you want to do this.

Comment: It would look nicer.

Comment: That's fair enough. For some reason I was imagining a middle manager forcing people to code with the company logo in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's IDLE IDE uses the python module `tkinter`, which interfaces to the tcl/tk graphics framework. While the latter allows optional images for some 'small' widgets, like buttons, it only allows solid color backgrounds for the big widgets.